# Constraint Flow percentage not working proper

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I am using `constraintlayout` `version 2.0.0-beta2`

Constraint Flow percentage not working properly. I am constructing chain using constraint flow helper. I am trying to apply percentage based constraints but not working as expected. 3 boxes should be arrange in horizontal & percentage constraint should be applied

**Layout XML**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.helper.widget.Flow
            android:id="@+id/flow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:constraint_referenced_ids="textView1,textView2,textView3"
            app:flow_horizontalStyle="packed"
            app:flow_maxElementsWrap="3"
            app:flow_verticalAlign="center"
            app:flow_verticalStyle="packed"
            app:flow_wrapMode="chain"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.4"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView1 Tex TextView1 Tex TextView1 Tex TextView1 TexTextView1 TexTextView1 Tex TextView1 Tex" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.4"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView1 Tex TextView1 Tex TextView1 Tex TextView1 TexTextView1 TexTextView1 Tex TextView1 Tex" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.2"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView1 Tex TextView1 Tex TextView1 Tex TextView1 TexTextView1 TexTextView1 Tex TextView1 Tex" />
        </LinearLayout>


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Issue Tracker ID:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/144667391

Answer (score -1):

Check following if it resolves your problem,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="20dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.helper.widget.Flow
        android:id="@+id/flow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="textView1,textView2,textView3"
        app:flow_horizontalStyle="packed"
        app:flow_maxElementsWrap="3"
        app:flow_verticalAlign="center"
        app:flow_verticalStyle="spread"
        app:flow_wrapMode="chain"
        app:flow_horizontalGap="20dp"
        app:flow_verticalGap="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView1 Tex TextView1 Tex TextView1 Tex TextView1 TexTextView1 TexTextView1 Tex TextView1 Tex" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView1"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView1 Tex TextView1 Tex TextView1 Tex TextView1 TexTextView1 TexTextView1 Tex TextView1 Tex" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView1 Tex TextView1 Tex TextView1 Tex TextView1 TexTextView1 TexTextView1 Tex TextView1 Tex" />
    </LinearLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Edited the answer, you can check if it meets your requirement

Comment: Thank you @Vijay. but along with this i need percentage based partition

Comment: what the heck, the point of flow is atto get rid of nestled linear layouts